# npm install is failing at libxmljs@0.18.8 install

Tags: node.js, npm

npm install is failing at

5720 timing command:install Completed in 170818ms
5721 verbose stack Error: command failed
5721 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\promise-spawn\lib\index.js:63:27)
5721 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
5721 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
5721 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
5722 verbose pkgid libxmljs@0.18.8
5723 verbose cwd C:\Sharmila\code
5724 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
5725 verbose node v16.17.0
5726 verbose npm  v8.19.2
5727 error code 1
5728 error path C:\Sharmila\code\node_modules\libxmljs
5729 error command failed
5730 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --loglevel http
5731 error Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
5731 error   libxmljs.cc

dependencies in package.json file

"dependencies": {
"date-parse": "^0.2.0",
"fixed-data-table": "^0.6.5",
"jquery": "^3.6.1",
"jquery-ui": "^1.13.2",
"react": "^15.0.0",
"react-dom": "^15.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"babel-cli": "6.26.0",
"babel-core": "6.26.3",
"babel-loader": "8.2.5",
"babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "6.26.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
"chokidar": "1.4.2",
"cli-color": "1.1.0",
"create-index": "^0.1.3",
"cross-env": "^5.0.0",
"css-loader": "0.23.1",
"eslint": "^2.13.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^6.0.0",
"eslint-config-google": "^0.4.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^4.2.3",
"excel-as-json": "^2.0.1",
"express": "4.13.4",
"faker": "^3.0.1",
"file-loader": "0.8.5",
"fs-extra": "0.26.5",
"json-loader": "0.5.4",
"lodash": "4.1.0",
"style-loader": "0.13.0",
"url-loader": "0.5.7",
"webpack": "5.74.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "4.11.0"
}

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/libxmljs2 which works with node v12

Also, make sure you don't have anything depending on older versions of iconv.

If you do, manually update the version of other packages so they don't include the old iconv.